# What is this mother doing?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, idioms

I would write a dialogue piece between a mother and a son who are having a heated argument over something. The son is very angry at his mother because he is suffering from disease and frustrated with his mother as she is not listening to what he is saying and instead, is busy in herself

> .
>
> .
>
> Son: *JUST GO AWAY AND KEEP PLAYING YOUR ONLINE GAME. YOU ARE SO
>   IRRESPONSIBLE* ....**rant**....
>
> Mother(in a calm manner): *I don't have to play it anymore. I have
>   already crossed the level I was playing.*
>
> .
>
> .

It seems that mother is not able to pacify her son and she is clueless about why he is angry. She is not even taking her son's anger seriously which obviously adds to the resentment in the child.

What is this mother doing here?

The mother is acting ______ and not acknowledging her son's anger which was expressed in a sarcastic manner(reverse psychology gone wrong).

She is talking about the trivial issues and not focusing on the 'argument', possibly unable to read between the lines.

Comment: The mother is clearly behaving *selfishly* - but I sense that is not the word you wanted. She is needlessly *preoccupied* with what she is doing. She is *oblivious* to her son's needs.

Comment: *oblivious*, *detached*, *indifferent*, *uninterested*?

Comment: This is a question about psychology, not English.

Comment: @HotLicks I just wanted to label this action. How do I put this question in a manner so that it would rightfully belongs to ELU?